# Dimension of Unstable Manifolds of the Equilibrium Points Connected by a Heteroclinic Orbit

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

Consider the ODE
\begin{align}
\dot x = f(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
Let $x_0$ and $y_0$ be hyperbolic critical elements (fixed points or periodic solutions) of $(1)$, and let $W^u$ and $W^s$ denote the unstable and stable manifolds. Assume that the intersection of stable and unstable manifolds of $x_0$ and $y_0$ satisfy the transversality condition and $\{W^u(x_0)- x_0 \} \cap \{W^s(y_0)- y_0 \} \ne \emptyset $. Then according to [Smale](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183529092) we have
$$\text{dim} \: W^u(x_0) \ge \text{dim} \: W^u(y_0)$$

where the equality sign holds when $x_0$ is an equilibrium point and $y_0$ is a closed orbit.

I appreciate it if anyone can provide an intuition for this result. I cannot justify this for the [pendulum heteroclinic orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroclinic_orbit) where both $x_0$ and $y_0$  are equilibrium points, but their unstable manifolds have the same dimension.

Comment: In the case of pendulum, the intersection of unstable and stable manifolds is non-transversal, so you can't apply the statement to it. Can you point to particular page in Smale's survey where this statement is written?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Correct, I did not pay attention to the transversality assumption.
I think it is related to the theorem on page 753 of Smale's paper. I saw this lemma from this paper: https://doi.org/10.1109/9.357  (lemma 3-5), but there is no proof in this paper and the authors refer to Smale’s paper.

Comment: So, I think I need to revise the title of my question. The condition mentioned in the question may not be related to heteroclinic orbits. That was my interpretation. Is that right?

Comment: To me the title is okay (but that's not a guarantee for others). Proof of inequality itself is not very hard: from transversality of intersection at point $x$ you have $T_x W^u(p) + T_x W^s(q) = T_x \mathcal{M}$, hence $\textrm{dim}\, T_x W^u(p) + \textrm{dim}\, T_x W^s(q) - \textrm{dim}\, T_x (W^u(p) \cap W^s(q)) = n$, where $\textrm{dim}\, \mathcal{M} = n$. But also (in case of hyperbolic equilibrium) you have that $\textrm{dim}\, W^u(q) + \textrm{dim}\, W^s(q) = n$. You can combine these two equalities and simply get an inequality you want.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm still a bit unsure about proof for periodic orbits.